# Installing a 50 amp sub panel

Tags: subpanel

Can I install a 50amp sub panel to a detached garage if I only have 3 wires running? Just bought the house and wire is already there.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What kind/gauge wire are we talking here?

Comment: What loads do you want to run off this subpanel?

Comment: What are the colors of the 3 wires?  What do you want to run?

Comment: It is 2 Black 2 gauge and 1 yellow 4 gauge. It’s a pretty long run I’d say over 200 ft. Looking to run a couple 20 amp breakers and one 220.